# Prove or disprove : $f=0$ a.e. on $\{x:|x|\geq 1\}$ if $\int_{\mathbb{R}}|x|^n|f(x)|dx\leq 1$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm studying real analysis and I have encountered a question: if $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and if $\int_{\mathbb{R}}|x|^n|f(x)|dx\leq1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, then does it follow that $f=0$ a.e. on $\{x:|x|\geq1\}$? I have tried to prove this by partitioning $\mathbb{R}$ into $\{x:|x|<1\}$ and $\{x:|x|\geq1\}$, but I couldn't solve this. How can I prove this, or disprove it by counterexample?

Comment: Have you tried something like $f(x)=e^{-x}$ of $e^{-x^2}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the answer is yes. It suffices to prove: if $f$ is not almost-everywhere equal to $0$ on $\{|x|\ge1\}$, then $\int_{\Bbb R} |x^nf(x)|\,dx$ tends to $\infty$.

Hint: show that the hypothesis implies the existence of an $\epsilon>0$ and a set $A\subset\Bbb R\setminus(-1,1)$ of positive measure such that $|f(x)|\ge\epsilon$ for all $x\in A$. Show further that one may assume that $A\subset\Bbb R\setminus(-1-\delta,1+\delta)$ for some $\delta>0$. Then bound $\int_A |x^nf(x)|\,dx$ from below.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't understand why $|f(x)|>\varepsilon$ for all $x\in A$. Can you explain it to me?

Comment: The hypothesis gives us a set $B$ of positive measure such that $|f(x)|>0$ for all $x\in B$. Consider the sets $B_k = \{ x\in B \colon |f(x)| > \frac1k \}$. Can all of $B_1,B_2,\dots$ have measure $0$? If they did, what would that say about $B$?

Comment: Ah now I understand. Thanks.